# Given a pivot point, sort a set of points in increasing order of angle which they make with the pivot point

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, optimization, convex-hull

As said in the title we need to sort the points in increasing order of angles.

I am taking the cross product with pivot point and other points. *If the cross product considering any two points with the pivot point is positive, it means that those two points are sorted in the increasing order.*

I am unable to find the mistake in this idea but this does not work. The code is:

```
//Here,a[0] is the pivot point.

//pivot is a global variable assigned to a[0].

vector<pair<int, int>>a(n);

sort(a.begin() + 1, a.end(), comp);

int comp(pair<int, int> x, pair<int, int> y) {
    int cross_product = crpd(pivot, x, y);

    if (cross_product >= 0)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int crpd(pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b, pair<int, int> c) {
    //y2*x1 - y1*x2
    int y2 = a.second - c.second;
    int x2 = a.first - c.first;
    int y1 = a.second - b.second;
    int x1 = a.first - b.first;
    int ans = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1;
    return ans;
}
```

```
Sample Input:

Pivot: (0,-4)

Points: [ (-5,0) , (-5,1) , (-4,2) , (-3,3) , (-1,4) , (5,0) , (4,-3) , (0,-4) , (-4,-3) ] 
Expected Output: [ (4,-3) , (5,0) , (-1,4) , (-3,3) , (-4,2) , (-5,1) , (-5,0) , (-4,-3) ]
Displayed Output: [ (-5,0) , (4,-3) , (5,0) , (-1,4) , (-3,3) , (-4,2) , (-5,1) , (-4,-3) ]
```

If anyone finds any mistake anywhere please answer

Comment: What makes you think there's a mistake? Share any input that fails, along with expected output.

Comment: *"As said in the question"* -- I find this hard to accept when these are the first words of the question. Perhaps you meant "as said in the title" and for some reason thought that copying that information into the question to make the question self-contained was a bad idea?

Comment: `long long ans = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1` you're performing operation on int so you'll get an int. Cast the operands to long long for correct results.

Comment: @theWiseBro , thanks for the suggestion , but even if the return type is int I get the wrong output.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-product "as-is" gives only sign of angle because your vectors are not normalized (unit length). Dividing by magnitudes of vectors is a step in correct direction but it gives possible range of  angles `-Pi/2..Pi/2`

You can get comparable value - angle in full range `-Pi..Pi` using `atan2`

```
angle = atan2(x1 * y2 - x2 * y1, x1 * x2 + y1 * y2);
```